# Can I declare a custom function in code section?

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm trying to declare and call a function in `php` code section of a partial but october does not see it.
Here is what the code looks like:

```
function onStart() {
    return sayHi();
}

function sayHi() {
    return 'Hi';
}
```

Would you please tell me what is wrong about this?
Are the only allowed functions here those which relate to page life cycle? (onStart(), onEnd(), onInit(), onRun() .. etc)

Comment: Have you gone through with this https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be helpful sometimes with such questions to include the actual error message that you receive if there is one, so that people don't start guessing wildly in the wrong direction. And in this case there should actually appear an error message like:

> ERROR: Call to undefined function sayHi()

The reason for this error here is that the functions in the template's code section are not defined in a global scope, but as methods of some object. So to reference each other, you would have to precede each cross function call inside the section with a `$this->` to specify that you are calling a method of the current object, and not a global function.

Changing your `ònStart()` function to

```
function onStart() {
    return $this->sayHi();
}
```

should make it work.

However, you might want to think about what you want to achieve with that return statement. The way the onStart() and other lifecycle functions in October are designed, a return statement is normally not expected. But if it exists, the page execution cycle is halted at that point and the return value is simply sent as a response back to the browser.

If you would simply like to display the message 'Hi' on the page (and before everything else), then you could perhaps better do it like this:

```
function onStart()
{
    $this->sayHi();
}

function sayHi()
{
    echo "<h1>Hi!</h1>";
}
```

so that the page rendering cycle still continues afterwards. But this would still be no good actually, because the `"<h1>Hi!</h1>"` is now put out before *everything* else (that is, before the opening `<html>` tag or whatever comes at the top).

I guess you did not actually want to use it that way, other than for functionality testing purposes, but anyway, thought it might be good to explain, so that people get an idea what actually happens there if they stumble across it. ;)

<sub>(On a related note, here is some documentation about proper usage for [sending a custom response in OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/pages#life-cycle-response).)</sub>

---

<sub>(If you'd like to have a dedicated stackechange community for OctoberCMS, plese support the [octobercms.stackexchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms). I'll remove this annoing message, once that goal is achieved - promise :) )</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, trollkotze, you saved my day! 
And yes you are right I wanted the functionality :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. If this has solved your problem I would appreciate if you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This way I get more reputation and people can also see immediately that this problem has been solved.

Comment: Also, if you have not yet done so, please support the [proposal for a dedicated OctoberCMS stackexchange section here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms?referrer=gRoetJyisyYjkvxz3ZCKeA2). As soon as we get at least 200 users committing to support this, and some with enough reputation elsewhere, the proposal will be accepted.
So your little contribution could help us all to get a better centralized place for building an OctoberCMS Q&A knowledge base on this great stackexchange platform. :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function sayHi() {
    return 'Hi';
   }

function onStart() {
    return sayHi();
   }
```

other wise when the execution reach `return sayHi();` it won't know function `sayHi()`. some [literature about it...](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: the only reason why a function won't recognize another is that it is being declared and call from a point in code where the other isn't declared, so I believe your issue relies in how your code is organized and the order your files are being "compiled"...